# Python common word finder

Tags: python

I have a small program that looks at a text file and displays how many time the word was used. Instead of printing words, it prints most commonly used letters not words and I don't understand what the problem.

```
import re
from collections import Counter

words = re.findall(r'\w', open('words.txt').read().lower())
count = Counter(words).most_common(8)
print(count)
```

Comment: You don't split the text from the file into a list of words, you're counting characters in the whole string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import string    
words = open('words.txt').read().lower()
# skip punctuation 
words = words = words.translate(str.maketrans('', '',string.punctuation)).split()
count = Counter(words).most_common(8)
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps, this is a regular expression answer and should go word by word.

```
import re
with open("words.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in re.findall(r'\w+', line):
            # word by word
```

if you do not have quotes around your data and you just want one word at a time (ignoring the meaning of spaces vs line breaks in the file) try this:

```
with open('words.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
           print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

in `regex` `\w` means just any character, not any word. You can get a list of words doing:

```
words= ' '.split( open('words.txt').read().lower())
```

And then you perform what you were doing:

```
count = Counter(words).most_common(8)
print(count)
```

I guess that should suffice, tell me if it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have following text file:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
>   reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
>   pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
>   culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

And you want to calculate words frequency:

```
import operator

with open('text.txt') as f:
    words = f.read().split()

result = {}
for word in words:
    result[word] = words.count(word)

result = sorted(result.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
print(result)
```

You'll get list of words with number of occurences for each word sorted descending:

> [('in', 3), ('dolor', 2), ('ut', 2), ('dolore', 2), ('Lorem', 1),
>   ('ipsum', 1), ...